# Centering a floating div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have just inherited some code and part of that code is to show a floating div and center it.

Here is the code:

```
function showFloatingDialog(element) {
  removeMessage();
  var height, width;
  var offsetY = $(document).scrollTop();

  if (offsetY == undefined) {
    offsetY = 0;
  }

  var dialog = $('#' + element);

  dialog.show();

  height = (($(window).width() - dialog.width()) / 2);
  width = ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2;
  width = width + offsetY;

  height = height - 195;
  width = width - 130;

  dialog.css('position', 'absolute');
  dialog.css('left', height + 'px');
  dialog.css('top', width + 'px');
}
```

In its defense, it works perfectly but I the following lines look like a hack:

```
  width = width + offsetY;

  height = height - 195;
  width = width - 130;
```

Is there a better and neater way of getting the same result than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question seems to have an awful lot of code to do what I thought was relatively simple. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/LHSDU/1/

```
var width = ($(window).width() - dialog.width()) / 2;
var height = ($(window).height() - dialog.height()) / 2;

dialog.css({'position' : 'absolute' , 'left' : width + 'px', 'top' : height + 'px'});
```

Comment: This is a solid and clean approach.  Also, it inadvertantly solves the vertical-align/display: table-cell glitch.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to centre a floating div, the example youve given isnt perhaps the best way but it resembles one of the ways you can do it in pure css.

Here is a good link with a little more info on it.
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Using

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

will set it horizontally centred

Comment: But this could result in a problem, as you cannot click the underlying parts of the page on the sides of the overlay.
And besides that, he has to use javascript after all to center the div in vertical direction.

Comment: I see your point but you dont HAVE to use javascript to centre it vertically, this can also be done via CSS. It all depends on your approach. The link that I posted is a bit of a give away being called "Vertical centering with css"

Comment: oh, my bad. Didn't catch the "Vertical" in your link, sorry for that! 
I wasn't aware of some of those techniques, so thank you for the link. One thing I'm curious about, are they still positioning correctly when the window gets resized?

Comment: No problem :) If your using percentages then from what I remember it will stay centred. If you need to explicitly place it given pixels then it would not update with resize other than on a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine those subtractions are to take half the width and height of the element to be centered. To make this dynamic you just need to replace that with the value of half of the width and height of the element to be positioned.

```
height = (($(window).width() - (dialog.width() / 2)) / 2);
width = ($(window).height() - (dialog.height() / 2)) / 2;
```

Then you don't need to subtract anything from the overall height and width.

Comment: Beat me to it, that seems about right. There are so many ways to centre, this is just one of them.

Comment: That places the div on the bottom right hand corner of the page.

Comment: Hard to say without having an example and knowing the size of the div your using but using this fix you shouldnt need the subtractions after the initial assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that you don't need the substractions if you use this